# Activating Mods per World

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In KSP, I have 2 worlds. One I play around doing real missions all in stock, the other, I use mods and mess around all the time.

I want to get Deadly Re-entry, but it will also affect my stock world. Is there a way I can enable mods for a specific save/world? Or do I have do disable them manually in the folders everytime I want to play?

Comment: Did you buy the Steam version, or are you using the version direct from Squad?  The reason I ask is that you really want to create two separate installs, which I hear is still possible with the Steam version, just not as easy.

Comment: @MBraedley I bought it on Steam. So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: _just not as easy_? Just copy the whole folder to another place. You get the original steam location via right clicking on the game->properties->local files tab->browse local files. It is a good idea to keep at least one copy untouched/vanilla, just in case your modded version becomes unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No, you have the mods installed for all saves or you don't have them at all.

The long answer is you can totally do that, but you have to install the game multiple times. I remember Scott Manly did an episode that covered how he could run different versions of KSP so he could run certain mods that are no longer supported.

[Kerbal Space Program - How To Backup Your Old Versions On Steam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRoKhjhu08Q)

He copies the entire KSP game folder and moves it to a repository. Then he just copies the version and mods he wants back to the regular location.

**Edit**: Copy the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Kerbal Space Program to another location (eg. Documents). Then when KSP updates you can revert to the old version by copying the file back.

Comment: So how would I go about doing this? You didn't really include instructions...

Comment: OK then. I will try this...

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked fine. Now I can enjoy blowing up ships while peacefully having them float in space at the same time. :3